# The order of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> The order of the smallest possible non trivial group containing elements $x$ and $y$ such that
>   $x^7 = y^2 = e $ and $ yx = x^4 y$  is
>
> 1. 1
> 2. 2
> 3. 7
> 4. 14

I am stuck on this problem. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Are these questions from Subject GRE?

Comment: Should we assume both $x$ and $y$ are nontrivial?

Comment: GRE means,?????

Comment: @Prasanta: The GRE refers to [this examination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Record_Examinations).

Comment: @ Ram,these questions are not from Subject GRE?

Comment: @anon, both $x,y$ may not be non trivial.

Comment: I'm with @anon on this. **Any** group contains such elements $x$ and $y$, because we can always take $x=y=1$. Of course, in some groups there can be other suitable pairs $(x,y)$, but this is irrelevant if the question is formulated as it is. So some kind of an additional non-triviality assumption is required to make the question at least a bit interesting.

Comment: @Ram not that it is important in this problem, but one can build an example in which $y$ is not trivial.

Comment: @DanShved yes you are right, 
but let's interpret the question as, the questions asks for minimum group and which should be non trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

1. Lagrange's theorem: For any finite group $G$, the order of every subgroup $H$ of $G$ divides the order of $G$.
2. $yx = x^4y$; $y(yx) = x$ do the manipulations using $yx = x^4y$ again and again and you will get $x = x^m$ for some $m \le 7 $ use that fact

Comment: assume $y \neq 0$ $yx = x^4y$ left multiply both sides by $y$ $ x = y x^4y$ $\Rightarrow $  $x = x^4yx^3y$ $\Rightarrow$ $ x = x^4x^4yx^2y$ finally you will get some relation between powers of $x$, you can use that.

Comment: @ Ram, I get $x=x^{16}$,so,$x=x^2$,so $x=e$....which is wrong??

Comment: Why that is wrong? Question doesn't mention that $x$ is non trivial.

Comment: If x = e, plug it back into the relations you are given. Can you find out anything new about y?

Comment: @  Billy, then order of y is 2,if $y \neq e$

Comment: Great. So you have a group with elements e (of order 1) and y (of order 2), with $y^2 = e$ and $y = y$. What is the smallest possible such group?

Comment: (Notice - in case it's confusing - that I got $y = y$ by taking the relation $yx = x^4 y$ and setting $x = e$, as you worked out yourself a few minutes ago.)

Comment: @  Billy,order of such group is 2, so,answer is 2,am I right??

Comment: Yes. (The *smallest* order of such a group is 2. There are many other bigger groups which satisfy this - for example, take a cyclic group of order 500 generated by $g$, and set $y = g^{250}$.)

Comment: It would be helpful for me to improve my answers if reason for down vote is provided.
I gave this particular method as answer since these type of questions appear very frequently in Indian exams and I felt it would be nice if I give a general procedure.

Comment: @Prasanta, you can start from taking $x$ or $y$ $=$ $e$, but most of the times, people ask for non trivial $x,y$ in such questions.

Comment: okk Sir.......but,what is answer if both x,y are non-trivial

Comment: @Ram I downvoted because I feel that this is not the best approach to the question. There's no need to *prove* that $x=e$ when we can simply *set* it to equal $e$. Although I do agree that proving it can also improve one's understanding of the problem.

Comment: @DanShved,thanks for the reply, I completely agree with you, but as I said above I gave that general approach since such type of questions are very common in India for Grad entrance tests in Maths, and more usually they ask for non trivial elements.

Answer (score 4):

Up to isomorphism, there is only one group of order 1, one group of order 2, one group of order 7, and two groups of order 14. Figure out (or look up) what those groups are. Which ones are non-trivial? Look for suitable elements $x$ and $y$ in those groups. You may want to start from the smallest group and work your way up.

Comment: Nice answer, but I doubt that might be little advanced for him right now.

Answer (score 1):

First solution - $x=y=e$ satisfies the relations. The smallest non-trivial group has order 2, and the relations can be satisfied within that group.

Now suppose we want $x$ and $y$ distinct (not stated in the question).

If $x$ and $y$ are both non-trivial (i.e. $\neq e$) then the first relation shows that the group must contain non-trivial elements of orders 2 and 7, and then Lagrange means that the order of such a group must be divisible by 14. [note we have not used the second relation or shown it is compatible with this conclusion]

So to get a non-trivial group of order less than 14, one of $x$ or $y$ must be the identity. If we set $y=e$ we see that $x^7=x^3=1$ so that $x=e$, which is not what we want. If we set $x=e$ then $y^2=e$ and this can be done in a group of order 2.

Answer (score 1):

For any group of order $2, say~\{e,a\}$ taking $x=e,y=a$ satisfies both the equation.